# Check if nested includes/repeats are finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a timeline component, in that component I repeat through multiple objects (items). Each of these items have multiple sub-items that load a template through ng-include and some of these sub-items have a ng-repeat in them.

On the timeline I load the ng-include and thus the ng-repeats when a user clicks on a item. Then a few api calls are done and the content is rendered in the DOM. This takes about 250-750ms depending on how many sub-items etc are in a item.

I want to animate the item collapsing for a smooth experience. But I have to wait for the DOM to be rendered to calculate the collapsed height of the item by looping through each sub-item.

So I have to wait for the ng-include to load or wait for the ng-repeat to render.

So what I can do is add `onload="vm.ngIncludeComplete()"` to the ng-include of each sub-item. This has the issue of being fired multiple times if the item has multiple sub-items, also a issue that I still have to use a setTimeout because I have to wait for the ng-repeats in the ng-include to finish.

Another solution is going into the templates and add `on-finish-render="vm.finishedRendering()"` to the ng-repeat:

```
link (scope, element, attr) {
    if (scope.$last === true) {
        scope.$evalAsync(attr.onFinishRender);
    }
}
```

This would call a function at the lowest level (the ng-repeat in the sub-item) so I don't have to do a setTimeout but not each template in a sub-item has a ng-repeat and some templates have multiple ng-repeats so I would still call the function multiple times.

Oh yea, the functions do a `$broadcast`:

```
this.$rootScope.$broadcast('startRenderDom');
```

Are there other options?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would work, but when you handle the `$broadcast` you could increment a shared variable and then this same variable could be decremented in your `vm.finishedRendering()` method. Only perform your animation when the value reaches 0. You would have to somehow know if an item has sub-items or you'd increment and never get back to 0.

Comment: Just discussed this issue with a colleague as well and came to a similar solution. I'll try to get something like that going and report back. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the correct way of doing this but it seems to be working.

```
public ngIncludeComplete() {
    this.i += 1;
    if (this.i === this.activities.items.length) {
        this.$rootScope.$broadcast('eventBroadcastedName');
    }
}
```

This function gets called every time a template is finished loading. I know how many sub-items are in a item (activity) so I can compare the incremental loop variable against the length of sub-items. Once it's equal it does the `$broadcast` so it's only fired once.

I'm not 100% sure if this also fixes the need for a setTimeout on the ng-repeat items inside the templates though. Initial testing seems to be fine.